# SQL Select Best practice

Tags: sql

The following works, I'm just wondering if this is the correct approach to finding the latest value for each audit field.

```
USE tempdb
CREATE Table Tbl(
TblID Int,
AuditFieldID Int,
AuditValue Int,
AuditDate Date
)
GO
INSERT INTO Tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(1,10,101,'1/1/2001')
INSERT INTO Tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(2,10,102,'1/1/2002')
INSERT INTO Tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(3,20,201,'1/1/2001')
INSERT INTO Tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(4,20,202,'1/1/2009')


SELECT AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate
FROM Tbl A
WHERE TblID=
(SELECT TOP 1 TblID
FROM Tbl
WHERE AuditFieldID=A.AuditFieldID
ORDER BY AuditDate DESC
)
```

Comment: sql.... server?  You should specify which technology you're using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate/ranking to get key and latest date, join back to get value.

This assumes SQL Server 2005+

```
DECLARE @tbl Table (
TblID Int,
AuditFieldID Int,
AuditValue Int,
AuditDate Date
)

INSERT INTO @tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(1,10,101,'1/1/2001')
INSERT INTO @tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(2,10,102,'1/1/2002')
INSERT INTO @tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(3,20,201,'1/1/2001')
INSERT INTO @tbl(TblID,AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate) VALUES(4,20,202,'1/1/2009')


;WITH cLatest AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AuditFieldID ORDER BY AuditDate DESC) AS Ranking,
        AuditFieldID, AuditDate
    FROM
        @tbl
)
SELECT
    A.AuditFieldID, A.AuditValue, A.AuditDate
FROM
    @tbl A
    JOIN
    cLatest C ON A.AuditFieldID = C.AuditFieldID AND A.AuditDate = C.AuditDate
WHERE
    C.Ranking = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

SELECT top 1 AuditFieldID,AuditValue,AuditDate
FROM Tbl
order by AuditDate DES

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods for doing this.  Different methods perform differently.  I encourage you to look at this blog which explains the various methods.

[Including an Aggregated Column's Related Values](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/including-an-aggregated-column-s-related)

Comment: Yes, this has 5 different ways and explained very detailed as well

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the where statement as you are already selecting from tbl A AND selecting on the same field.